# Why is myreact component not displaying on mobile

Tags: reactjs, timer, components

This one is driving me crazy. I have a countdown timer component. It's showing up fine on localhost and desktop after build but not showing up on mobile devices after build. Can anyone please tell me what this could be ?

Here is the component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";


const CountdownTimer = () => {

  const getCountdown = () => {
    const year = new Date().getFullYear() + 1;
    const timeRemaining = new Date(`2022-6-13`) - new Date();
    let countdown = {};
    if (timeRemaining > 0) {
      countdown = {
        Days: Math.floor(timeRemaining / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
        Hours: Math.floor((timeRemaining / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
        Minutes: Math.floor((timeRemaining / 1000 / 60) % 60),
        Seconds: Math.floor((timeRemaining / 1000) % 60),
      };
    }
    return countdown;
  };
  const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState(getCountdown());

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCountdown(getCountdown());
    }, 1000);
  });

  const data = [];
  Object.entries(countdown).forEach(([unit, value]) => {
    data.push(
      <div style={{ 
        display: "inline-block",
        margin: "0 20px",
        fontSize: "20px"}} key={Math.random().toString(16)}>
        <strong>{value}</strong> {unit}
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div style={{
      marginTop: '1px'
    }}>
      <h2></h2>
      <ul>{data}</ul>
    </div>
  );
  
};
export default CountdownTimer;
```

adding to the desired page in a div like this

```
          <div className='countdowntimer'>
              <CountdownTimer />
            </div>
```

CSS looks like this

```
.countdowntimer {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px;
    font-size: 20px;

    
  }
```

app.jsx looks like this

```
export const scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]', {
  speed: 1000,
  speedAsDuration: true,
});

const App = () => {
  const [landingPageData, setLandingPageData] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    setLandingPageData(JsonData);
  }, []);

  return (
    
    <div>
      <Navigation />
      <Header data={landingPageData.Header} />
      <About data={landingPageData.About} />
      <Services data={landingPageData.Services} />
      <Meet data={landingPageData.Meet} />
      <Contact data={landingPageData.Contact} />
    </div>

  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `useEffect` hook in the component by adding an empty array(`[]`) as a second argument.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCountdown(getCountdown());
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

I think this would be the solution to your problem. Please give it a try-out.

**Why is the useEffect cleanup useful?**

The useEffect cleanup helps developers clean effects that prevent unwanted behaviors and optimizes application performance.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help. Sadly it's still not displaying on mobile devices.